# Nested Repeaters using DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, repeater, asprepeater

I could not properly bind my child repeater (lvTwo) using a datatable. It always throws a NullReferenceException. On debug mode, my datatable looked fine, any thoughts?

HTML Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="lvOne" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lvOne_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            I am the one.
        </div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="lvTwo" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                I am the two.
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind (dtTable to bind for lvOne, dtTable2 to bind for lvTwo):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
        dtTable.TableName = "T1";
        dtTable.Columns.Add("ProjectName");

        DataRow dr = dtTable.NewRow();
        dr["ProjectName"] = "ThreeSixFive";
        dtTable.Rows.Add(dr);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lvOne.DataSource = dtTable;
            lvOne.DataBind();
        }
    }


protected void lvOne_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtTable2 = new DataTable();
        dtTable2.TableName = "T2";
        dtTable2.Columns.Add("C");

        DataRow dr = dtTable2.NewRow();
        dr["C"] = "ThreeSixFive";
        dtTable2.Rows.Add(dr);

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            if (dtTable2 != null)
            {
                lvTwo.DataSource = dtTable2;
                lvTwo.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Check whether you have initialized lvOne or lvTwo .. Also where does the exception thrown from ?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was due to the unrecognized lvTwo control. It was able to compile due to the control being registered in the designer file, instead I need to use the ff:

```
var lvTwo = (ListView) e.Item.FindControl("lvTwo");
```